# How to define Navigator.pop() response type in Child widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

Parent Widget

```
String pincode = await Navigators.root.currentState.push(
  MaterialPageRoute<String>(
    builder: (context) => ChildWidget(),
  ),
);
```

Child Widget

```
Navigators.root.currentState.pop(pincode);
```

**My concerns:**

1. If someone change the Child `.pop` response to `bool`.
   IDE will never know and show warnings in Parent Widget.
2. If you don't look into the Child widget implementation,
   you will not know what type does it return.

---

**current solution**

```
class ChildResult {
  final String pincode;
  ChildResult({ this.pincode });
}

class Child extends HookWidget {
    ...
    Navigators.root.currentState.pop(ChildResult(pincode: pincode));
    ...
}
```

My current solution is to create a `[Widget]Result` class,
and told my coworker to remain same practice for all widget,
so at least I can preview what's value name / type in IDE.

**Is there any other solution?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is impossible at the moment to define a type for the pop function on the Navigator. When you call the pop the type is dynamic because it is unaware of which page (widget) it will be popped to in the stack.